# Animate if scrollTop less than specified value - does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

ease-scroll is a div with one anchor tag in it.

```
<div id="ease-scroll">
    <a href="#">&uarr; Top</a>      
</div>
```

I need the div's opacity to be 0.9 when scrollTop() is greater than 450, and this works as expected, and if I now scroll *up* thereby scrollTop() value is less than 450, I want to revert the opacity to original value 0.1. But, revert opacity value is not happening.
Any clue what is wrong?

```
// Help navigate!
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.9 ) {
       jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.9}, 'medium');
    }
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.1 ) {
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.1}, 'medium');
    }
});
```

Comment: if jQuery(window).scrollTop() == 450 then what is do ??

Comment: @Peter O. avoid such minor edit changes. It's not welcome in our community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/upojob/2/edit)*

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

   $(window).scroll(function(){
       
      var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
      $("#ease-scroll").stop().animate({opacity: (scrolled>450 ? 0.9 : 0.1) }, 600);

   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful, although I had to change $('body').scrollTop(); to $(window).scrollTop() Perhaps, it works in jsBin because its body is inside a iframe that scrolls there.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll event is fired plenty of times when user is scrolling. Use animation() for each event is not a good idea because it takes user CPU ressources for nothing.

Here is a workaround :

```
// Help navigate!
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
    jQuery("#ease-scroll").stop(); // stop animation before anything else
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.9 ) {
       jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.9}, 'medium');
    }
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.1 ) {
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.1}, 'medium');
    }
});
```

But you should define a setTimeOut which is reset if needed to avoid CPU utilization for nothing (not tested, possible small syntax error :o)

```
// Help navigate!
var animationTimeout = null;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 

    // Clear planned animation
    clearTimeout(animationTimeout);

    // Define animation start after 500 ms if no others scroll events occurred

    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.9 ) {
        animationTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").stop();
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.9}, 'medium');
        },500);
    } 
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 450 && jQuery("#ease-scroll").css("opacity") != 0.1 ) {
        animationTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").stop();
        jQuery("#ease-scroll").animate( {opacity: 0.1}, 'medium');
        },500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for explaining about resource usage. I actually thought about it when alert() added for debugging fired multiple times, couldn't figure out how to stop(). It works as-is No syntax errors :)